# What is the meaning of the phrase "X° of frost?"

Tags: meaning

I ran across this phrase in The Cherry Orchard: "3 degrees of frost," and I assumed it was a colloquialism for 3 degrees AND frost, or something of the like. But I just ran into "45° of frost" elsewhere, so it is not a colloquialism and "of" does not represent "and," for that would be impossible, right?

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to ELU. I think your question might get closed as "general reference", but briefly - *"x degrees of frost"* simply means *"x degrees below 0C"* (i.e. - below the freezing point of water).

Comment: +1 to @FumbleFingers.  Wikipedia to the rescue:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_frost

Comment: @Iszi: And +1 to you! Your Wikipedia link makes clear what I knew was missing from my comment - that to lots of older people (older than me, I mean!) **30° of frost** means 2°F (32-30), which is actually only about -16°C. Positively balmy compared to -30°C!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Who're you calling "older people"?  You're nearly as old as my mother-in-law!  We just happen to live on the other side of the pond.

Comment: @Iszi: Actually, I had in mind my own father - who's 90, and lives a couple of hundred miles north of me. We're having a bit of a cold snap here in the UK, and I was on the phone to him yesterday. I honestly don't recall, but he might easily have said *"We had 10° of frost last night"*. I think in Centigrade, so if he had, I'd have assumed things were much worse up there than down here in the "Garden of England", where we only had 5° of frost. But thanks to you, next time I'll know he's *just as cold*, not *"twice" as cold"* (but you do feel the cold more when you're older, bless him! :)